# before check ModelState.IsValid I am bind a value ,after that model state id failed

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

Before validating the model state, I am binding a value in my model. It does not take the value and `ModelState.IsValid` not working

```
tickMarkModel.CompanyId =(long) AuthInformation.companyId;
try
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try {           
            return Ok(_tickMarkApplicationService.SaveTickmark(tickMarkModel));
        }
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that clarifies your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: remove it as required field if you are not validating through modelstate.isvalid